# multiple pandas column by itself to produce an array

Tags: python, pandas

Given a list (vector) like this:

```
index    values
item 1   0.05
item 2   0.1
item 3   0.35
...
item n   0.0n
```

How can one produce an array of the products of each item with itself such that the answer takes this form using a vectorized method (i.e. no for loops):

```
index    item 1   item 2   item 3 ...  item n
item 1   1*1      1*2      1*3    ...  1*n
item 2   2*1      2*2      
item 3   3*1      3*2     
...          
item n   n*1      n*2             ...  n*n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting for multiple Series each other:

```
a = df['values'].to_numpy()
i = df.index.to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame(a * a[:, None], index=i, columns=i)
print (df)
        item 1  item 2  item 3
item 1  0.0025   0.005  0.0175
item 2  0.0050   0.010  0.0350
item 3  0.0175   0.035  0.1225
```

Comment: This looks very close to what i am seeking. however, i notice that `index` appears twice, so the resulting dataframe is multi index. is it possible to remove this?

Comment: @D.L - answer was edited.

Comment: I have marked this as the accepted answer as it completely answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('v'))

df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbuJy.png)

```
for i in range(1,5):
    df[f"v_{i}"]=df["v"]*i
  

df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbbfb.png)

Comment: OP need `no for loops`

Comment: this is a good answer. However, i avoid loops as it would invariably be slower than the vectorized solution.

Comment: yes you're wrşght, i did not read complete question